# Magento EE FPC ignored when in https?

Tags: cache, magento-enterprise, full-page-cache

Whilst browsing the FPC code in `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor`, I cam e across this method:

```
/**
     * Check if processor is allowed for current HTTP request.
     * Disable processing HTTPS requests and requests with "NO_CACHE" cookie
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllowed()
    {
        if (!$this->_requestId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_COOKIE['NO_CACHE'])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($_GET['no_cache'])) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Mage::app()->useCache('full_page')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Thus, if I am reading this right, FPC is disabled when in HTTPS?
If a site is only run in HTTPS, is FPC thus pointless/no effect?

I have a site that is only in HTTPS, and FPC writes files to the folder, so what gives? Am I misunderstanding this code?

Anyone shed some light?

Comment: If magento is running under https, but the https is removed by load balancer, this function might return true :-) just an idea

Comment: ah, good point. I use pound for ssl termination, so yes that makes sense. if you place as an answer I will credit.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason why Magento is doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are correct with your interpretation, If the request ends as https at magento, FPC will do nothing.

But if you end https before, e.g. In the load balancer, the request will hit magento as http, therefore FPC will work.